# Can I use static methods when I don't have any instance variables?

Tags: java

I have a class as follows

```
class Myclass{
  //no instance  variables
 static boolean  validate(MyObj oj){
    //impl
   }

}
```

1. Now if 2 thread calls static method `Myclass.validate(param)` with different parameters at the same time ,will it work correctly? If yes/no, how?
2. Is my approach correct? I want to put some validation logic or some custom conversion utility in such static methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any instance variables, you have a utility class.

```
public enum Utility {;
   public static boolean validate(MyObj obj) ....

}
```

However a better approach is to move the method to the first parameter type, if you can.

```
public class MyObj {

   public boolean validate() ....
}
```

1. Provided the arguments are not shared, two threads can call the same method without thread safety issue.
2. If this is for validation, or conversion a utility class may be a better choice if you want more than one way to validate or convert the `MyObj` type.

Comment: It is not a better approach. In proper OOP an object should guard it's invariants every time it is modified so "validate" method is unnessesery. In this situation it is a utility method propably for argument validation (like commons.lang.Validate class) so it is ok to be static.

Comment: Are you arguing that a static method is better OO than a non-static method? :P

Answer (score 1):

1- Call is safe since the `obj` parameter is local to the method. However ensure that

- The Obj is not shared by different threads. If it is then sate is not
  modified. (should be immutable)
- The object re3fernce is not passed to    any alien method, which
  might be not thread safe.
- You can mark the    parameter as final.

2- Its OK to have static methods for classes which don't have any state.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it will work correctly. Parameters passed to a method lives in
   a memory area called the "stack" and each thread will have it's own
   stack.
2. I would say yes

Answer (score 0):

You use case is a perfect fit for an Utility class and making the utility class methods static will help you use the class without instantiating it (Hence avoiding object littering and GC overhead ). 
    Thread safety is not an issue here as you are using any shared variable (class variables). So you are safe that way.

So both #1 and 2# will work.